# I renewed my passport, can I still use my valid US B1/B2 visa if it is stamped on the old passport?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, passport-renewals

I have valid a B1/B2 visa till March 2016. Can I enter the US for 2 weeks in May 2015?
Also my passport has been renewed into a new book while the visa is stamped in the old passport. Is this still valid?

Comment: Yes, you can enter. Make sure to have both of your passports and make sure the visa page in the old passport is not punctured.

Answer (score 4):

Your visa can be used throughout its validity period, unless cancelled or revoked. Hence **you will be able to enter the USA on your current B-1/B-2 visa** since it is hasn't expired yet. Moreover, the visa remains valid until it expires (ha, nice tautology). This is true regardless if it is contained in an invalid/expired passport. All you need to do is make sure you bring both passports when seeking admission into the USA. Finally, [as IKeelYou suggests](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46254/change-of-passport#comment87777_46254) you should make sure that the visa page in the old passport is not damaged, to avoid any problems. Quoting from [the US Department of State - Bureau of Consular Affairs website](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html):

> #### Additional Information
>
> [...]
>
> - Unless canceled or revoked, a visa is valid until its expiration date.  Therefore, a valid U.S. visa in an expired passport is still valid. If you have a valid visa in your expired passport, do not remove it from your expired passport. You may use your valid visa in your expired passport along with a new valid passport for travel and admission to the United States.

The length of your stay is decided by the immigration officer who lets you in the country. [The maximum allowed stay on a B-1/B-2 visa is 6 months.](http://www.immihelp.com/visitor-visa/tourist-visa-faq.html)