# Does my mother need a new passport with my fathers new name to enter the US vith a B2 Visa?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

My Dad's passport had a name issue due to which he is in the process of changing it to get a new passport so as to reflect his new name (alias). My Mom's passport already has a US visitor visa stamped on it.

If my Dad is getting a new passport to reflect his new name, is it mandatory that my Mom's passport also needs to be changed to reflect the new name of the spouse? or can she just show the Gazette (proof of name change) without changing the passport during immigration?

If at all she has to change the passport, what is the process to get the visa imprinted again on her new passport?

Comment: The US is not going to pay any attention to your father's name as it appears in your mother's passport.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46254/i-renewed-my-passport-can-i-still-use-my-valid-us-b1-b2-visa-if-it-is-stamped-o?r=SearchResults

Comment: Is your mom changing her name?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Voting to put on hold.